# Condition for Integral Inequality

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, inequality

Consider the continuously differentiable vector $x\in\Re^{n\times 1}$. Given the following inequality holds: $$\int_{t_0}^{t_0+\tau}x(s)x^T(s).ds \ge \alpha.I_{n\times n}$$ 
where $I_{n\times n}$ is the unit matrix of dimension $n$, $\alpha>0$ is a scalar, $\tau>0$.

Then, for the same signal vector $x(t)$, I need to show that the following is valid;
$$\int_{t_0}^{t_0+\tau}\left(\int_{z}^{z+d} x(s).ds\right)\left(\int_{z}^{z+d} x^T(s).ds \right) .dz \ge \beta.I_{n\times n}$$ 
for some  scalar $\beta>0$, $\tau>0$ and $d>0$.

I got stuck with the solution, and need some hints (maybe more than hints). 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does $\ge$ mean here? And does $x$ as a function have certain properties?

Comment: $Q \ge I$ means $Q-I$ is positive semi-definite matrix. And $x$ has no particular properties. It is just a signal vector satisfying the above inequality.

Comment: Well, it must be at least integrable (even square-integrable), right (in whichever sense)?

Comment: Have you proved it in one dimension?

Comment: Haven't shown in 1-D, yet. Sorry for the missing details. $x$ is continuous and inyegrable.

Comment: Then please add this in your question.